# Warning: second/third operand of conditional has no effect [-Wunused-value]

Tags: c++, gcc, operator-precedence

```
std::cout << (abs(b - c) < a) && a < b + c ? 1 : 0;
```

I want to check if given values can create triangle. I got warnings:

```
second operand of conditional expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
third operand of conditional expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your code translates to:

```
((std::cout << (abs(b - c) < a)) && a < b + c) ? 1 : 0;
```

Firstly, **`operator<<` has higher [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `operator&&`.**

Only the value of `abs(b - c) < a` will be printed and the `(a < b + c ? 1 : 0)` part will be AND-ed together with the return value of [`std::ostream::operator bool`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool).

But the warning is about `1` and `0` not being assigned to anything nor having any side effects, because **`&&` precedes the ternary conditional (`?:`)**.

---

The correct code is either:

```
std::cout << (abs(b - c) < a && a < b + c ? 1 : 0);
// same as std::cout << ((abs(b - c) < a && a < b + c) ? 1 : 0);
```

or

```
std::cout << (abs(b - c) < a && (a < b + c ? 1 : 0));
```

In fact, they're equivalent (apart that one calls `operator<<` with `bool` and the other with `int`), no ternary operator needed:

```
std::cout << (abs(b - c) < a && a < b + c);
```

Comment: I meant `std::cout << ((abs(b-c) < a) && a < b+c ? 1:0);` one as it doesn't give warnings and gives expected result. Thank you for expanding your answer.